# A bb recipe to add file to both initramfs and root

Tags: yocto

I am trying to edit my bb recipe to install my app to initramfs as well as the root. The issue i am facing is do_install() I don't think i can have the install copy to ${D} as well as initramfs-basic/1.0-r0/rootfs/bin (I don't know the variable for that location unless its ${base_sbindir} but it doesn't show up there).

It will only show up in the root bin directory after the system has booted but nothing i do with also copy it to the initramfs drive. How can i copy to both locations?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out initramfs is just another image recipe. adding IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " myapp " added it to the initramfs as well as the root.